# Sidekiq failing a lot before succeeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I've set up sidekiq to run after_commit, but it fails (close to) 100% of the time with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with id=42635`.

For the longest time I thought it was connected to the wrong redis database, but with `retry: true` turned on I've found that it eventually succeeds after around 10 minutes.

Its very weird, because I can see our users in the admin panel with the id that failed, but sidekiq will still fail for a while then eventually a retry will work.  I have no idea what's causing this, I'd like to get it to succeed on the first try.

**Edit:**
Using AWS, example sidekiq call and worker below:

**In UserObserver:**

```
  def after_commit(user)
    if user.created_at == user.updated_at
      @user = user
      identify_and_track
    end
```

...

```
def identify_and_track
  IdentifyAndTrackUserWorker.perform_async(@user.id)
end
```

**Sidekiq worker:**

```
class IdentifyAndTrackUserWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: true

  def perform(user_id)
    @user = User.find user_id
    Analytics.identify(
      user_id: user_id,
      traits: { email:      @user.email,
                first_name: @user.first_name,
                last_name:  @user.last_name
              }
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: We need more details to be helpful. Are you using Heroku? A dedicated server? What's the SQL server—PG, MySQL, something else? Can you share some extracted code from Sidekiq worker?

Comment: @colinm - Updated question with a sidekiq worker.

Comment: @Ashbury I'm having the same exact issue. I'm also using `after_commit` but Sidekiq fails. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I don't have access to the repo anymore but I believe the issue was that redis/sidekiq are so fast they picked up the job before everything was updated on db (i know you're using after_commit, but maybe associated models?)  Sorry I can't remember.  You could try .perform_in(5.seconds) to diagnose if that's the problem.

Comment: @Ashbury I put `perform_in(60.seconds)` and I'm still getting not found errors. I can even see the job scheduled in Sidekiq Web and connect to the Rails console and look for the object and can find it, but Sidekiq fails... after I myself proved that the object exists

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Ashbury had the same issue. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems very similar to this one and have come to find out that Sidekiq, in it's speedy nature, is executing the job before Rails is able to create the object. To prevent sidekiq failure, it was helper to give Rails the time to create the object.

Use `IdentifyAndTrackUserWorker.perform_in(1.minute, @user.id)` rather than `IdentifyAndTrackUserWorker.perform_async(@user.id)`.